# Parse PCAP files for IGMPv3 packets with scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I'm attempting to parse IGMPv3 packets with the RawPcapReader in scapy. For some reason unbeknownst to me it's not detecting the IGMP layer:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import os.path
import sys

from scapy.contrib.igmpv3 import IGMPv3
from scapy.utils import RawPcapReader
from scapy.layers.l2 import CookedLinux
from scapy.layers.inet import IP


def pcap_parser(pcap_file):
    for (pkt_data, pkt_metadata) in RawPcapReader(pcap_file):

        ether_pkt = CookedLinux(pkt_data)
        if ether_pkt.proto != 0x800:
            # Ignore non-ip packets.
            continue

        ip_pkt = ether_pkt[IP]
        ip_proto = ip_pkt.fields['proto']
        if ip_proto == 2:
            igmp_pkt = ip_pkt[IGMPv3]


def _command_line_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--pcap', metavar='<input pcap file>', help='pcap file to parse', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args


def main():
    args = _command_line_args()

    if not os.path.exists(args.pcap):
        print(f'Input pcap file "{args.pcap}" does not exist', file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(-1)

    pcap_parser(args.pcap)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get a **IndexError: Layer [IGMPv3] not found** error, despite the packets being detected in Wireshark:

[image: wireshark screenshot]

Comment: I suggest you add *print(ip_pkt)* to see exactly what's in there

Comment: If I run ip_pkt.show(), its picking up a raw and padding layer after the IP layer instead of IGMP: IP >> Raw >> Padding. Invalid packet, perhaps?